# PHP sessions security

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I am not sure how to explain this, but basically I want users to navigate to a file called index.php on my apache server installed on the root directory on my site. Whenever they visit this URL, they get a session or cookie, something to tell my server that they visited this site with a timed expiration of 5 minutes. This will redirect them to another site, for example, http://bing.com. Whenever they get redirected to the same index.php on my site, the session will be read and if it is present and hasn't expired, use echo to display an iframe element. If there is no session or it has expired, redirect to http://bing.com.

I have tried this myself, but I am too much of an amateur. Here is my script:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if ((isset($_SESSION["visit"]) {
unset ($_SESSION['visit']);
echo "<p>Success</p><br><iframe src=secretpage.html width=100% height=95% frameBorder=0></iframe>"
}
 else {
    $_SESSION['visit']='true'; 
    header("Location: http://bing.com");
    die();
}
?>
```

I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: <strike>you don't start your session until AFTER you've already tried reading it, which sort of defeats the purpose of having the session in the first place. "I'll check if the trampoline is there on the way down after I jump off this cliff".</strike> And now that's been ninja-edited away.

Comment: @MarcB < s > blabla < / s > and no <strike></strike>

Comment: @Zl3n: nope. doesn't work.

Comment: In any case, exactly **HOW** is this code not working?Note that this "security system" is anything but. Anyone could inspect the page after they go through your "login" and get the url of the iframe.

Comment: A̶p̶p̶a̶r̶e̶n̶t̶l̶y̶,̶ ̶w̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶'̶t̶,̶ ̶w̶e̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶k̶i̶n̶d̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶[t̶o̶o̶l̶](http://adamvarga.com/strike/) - [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/is-there-a-way-to-strike-out-text-in-comments)

Comment: That is a fair point, people can inspect the result. Thanks for this resource anyway. I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['visit'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['visit']);
    echo '<p>Success</p><br><iframe src=secretpage.html width=100% height=95% frameBorder=0></iframe>';
} else {
    $_SESSION['visit']='true';
    header('Location: http://bing.com');
}
```